# JNI Method not found

Tags: android, c++, interface, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been receiving this error for my JNI code while I tried find the method ,using GetMethodID, my Java method is in an Interface.

Here is my interface

```
 public interface printReader 
 {

 public printImg readerPrint(String selectedName) throws Exception;

 }
```

Native code

```
WprintImgIMPL.h
class WprintImgIMPL: public IWprintReader  {

public:

    WprintImgIMPL(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
   ~WprintImgIMPL(void);

virtual WprintImg  readerPrint(char* readerName) ;
   .....
   .....
 private:
    JNIEnv *m_Env;
    jobject m_jObj;
 }

WprintImgIMPL.cpp
WprintImg  WprintImgIMPL::readerPrint(char* readerName) {
jclass cls = m_Env->GetObjectClass (m_jObj);

jmethodID mid = m_Env->GetMethodID (cls, "readerPrint", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/site/name/printImg;");
.......
.......
}
```

Java code

```
public class printReaderIMPL implements printReader {
static final String DEBUG_TAG = ""; 
android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;

Context _context;

public printReaderIMPL (Context context) {
    _context = context;
}

@Override
public printImg readerPrint(String selectedName) throws Exception { 

    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "readerPrint");
     }
}
```

Constructor/destructor

```
   WprintImgIMPL(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
     m_Env = env;
     m_jobj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);

  }
  ~WprintImgIMPL(void) {
     m_Env->DeleteGlobalRef(m_jobj);
  }

Error: GetMethodID: method not found: Lcom/site/name/NativeCode;.printImg:(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/site/name/printImg;
```

Signature are checked twice , after failure I generated again using Javap tool .

Thank you if you can input /comment and help in fixing this bug.

Comment: What does the declaration in the .h file look like? And the .c file? Do they agree?

Comment: Please see question back I have added native code as well.

Comment: and yes they are agree code compiles/links well , however unable to find the Method it crashed at GetMethodID.

Comment: It would help to see the declaration of m_jObj on the native side and the class that implements the interface (i.e., the interface implementation itself, not just the declaration) on the Java side.

Comment: Please see back again I updated with Java code as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you sure `m_jObj` and `cls` are getting set correctly?  (You didn't show what `m_jObj` is initialized to be, but I'm assuming it's initialized by the `jobject` you pass to the `WprintImgIMPL` constructor.)  The reason I ask about these is that I don't see anything obviously wrong with your method signature.

Comment: I have updated it further with the m_jobj initialization. I am considering it is getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid to save a `JNIEnv*` across JNI method calls. It's only valid for the duration of the JNI method you are currently in. Out of the blue, e.g. in arbitrary C++ code, you need to call `AttachCurrentThread()` to get a current valid `JNIEnv*`.

However you *can* cache the methodID. There no need to look it up every time. Look it up in your constructor.

Comment: Yeah I agreed and I have been registering object of WprintImgIMPL using constructor WprintImgIMPL(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) to the native object like nativeObj->registerPrintImg(printImge), printImge here is an object of WprintImgIMPL . and my native code has Javah generated header code.

Comment: I doubt I keep my nativeObj as global in native code, Java/JVM has no knowledge about that, I wonder if that's the issue ? however rest of the native registered function are working fine, like nativeObj->registerCPlusPlusCode worked.

Comment: are you saying before I register my object I should cache the medhodID and pass it to constructor as I have valid JNIEnv?

and I register nativeObj->registerPrintImg(printImge) object to the native which is like infinite loop and will keep running , that means my native method never exits so as per it should keep having valid JNIEnv?, I may be wrong just wanted to understand what does't it means.

Comment: No, I said you can look up the methodID *in* your constructor. I don't know what the part starting 'register' means. I think you need to post more code.